# Wrong complex integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, complex

I've tried to perform the following integral with mathematica (student edition):

```
Integrate[(I/Pi)/(-x + I/(2 t)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> t> 0]
```

Mathematica says that this integral doesn't converge but it is wrong, the right result is 1.
Is something wrong with the string?

Comment: By numerics: `NIntegrate[(I/Pi)/(-x + I/(2)), {x, -Infinity, -I, Infinity}, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"] // Quiet // Chop`

Comment: Will this be constructive: `Residue[(I/Pi)/(-x + I/(2 t)), {x, I/(2 t)}]`, which returns `-I/\[Pi]`?

Answer (score 13):

This integral exist only in the principal value sense:

```
Integrate[(I/Pi)/(-x + I/(2 t)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 Assumptions -> t > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> 1

That means, the integrand is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$, but still

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{\operatorname{i}}{\pi  \left(-x+\frac{\operatorname{i}}{2 t}\right)} \, \operatorname{d} x = 1$$

exists. The important point is that

$$ \int_{-S}^R \frac{\operatorname{i}}{\pi  \left(-x+\frac{\operatorname{i}}{2 t}\right)} \, \operatorname{d} x = 1$$

only converges if the lower and upper integral boundary $S$ and $R$ converge to $\infty$ with (essentially) same rate. The reason is that the imaginary part of the integrand is

```
Im[(I/Pi)/(-x + I/(2 t))] // ComplexExpand // TeXForm
```

> $$-\frac{x}{\pi  \left(\frac{1}{4 t^2}+x^2\right)},$$

so it is an odd function in $x$ and goes assymptotically like $\frac{1}{x}$ which is not (absolutely) integrable.

Comment: Ok it's clear now, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome!